# Changing a field in an XML document

Tags: xml, perl, debian

I have an XML file that has this structure:

```xml
<user-mapping>
  <authorize username="user2" password="asdasdsss" >
    <connection name="U2 - Windows 7 ">
      <protocol>rdp</protocol>
      <param name="hostname">192.168.203.2</param>
      <param name="port">21122</param>
      <param name="password">asdasdsss</param>
      <param name="username">user</param>
    </connection>
    <connection name="U2 - Windows XP SP3 ">
      <protocol>rdp</protocol>
      <param name="hostname">192.168.203.2</param>
      <param name="port">21120</param>
      <param name="password">asdasdsss</param>
      <param name="username">user</param>
    </connection>
  </authorize>
</user-mapping>
```

This file has around 20 users (`authorize` elements) and each user has around 15 machine connections.

I have created a Perl program to change only the password field, but it is based on counting lines and characters until the field is found. If I add additional `param` elements then the script has to be modified.

I want to have a dynamic way of doingit, so that Perl can select the correct user node and change the password field in all related machines. I tried many ways but I couldn't get it to work.

The password should be changed for the user and for all machines. They will all will be changed to the same password

My code which is used now:

```perl
open( FILL, "< /etc/user-mapping.xml" );

@strings = <FILL>;
$i = 0;

foreach $line (@strings) {
    print $i;
    print $line;
    $i++;
}

print "Number: ";
print $set_id;

$set_id = $set_id - 2;
$set_id = $set_id * 102;

print "Line: ";
print $set_id;

substr( @strings[ 1 + $set_id ],  43, 9 ) = "$password";
substr( @strings[ 6 + $set_id ],  39, 9 ) = "$password";
substr( @strings[ 13 + $set_id ], 39, 9 ) = "$password";

foreach $line ( @strings ) {
    print $i;
    print $line;
    $i++;
}

open( FH, "> /etc/user-mapping.xml" );
foreach $line (@strings) {
    print( FH $line );
}

close(FH);

close(FILL);
```

Comment: You should be using an XML parser if you're trying to modify XML data.

Comment: ...there are actually some *really great* XML parsers for perl, too.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Unfortunately there are even more clunky ones than great ones, and it's a minefield for the uninitiated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you understand that keeping passwords as plain text is a very bad idea?

You must use a proper XML parser, and I suggest that you use [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) as it is a little friendlier than some alternatives

Here's a program that does as you ask. It changes the password to `abc123` throughout. As you can see, it's even rather shorter than your original program

It uses XPath expressions to find all the `/user-mapping/authorize` elements in the document and changes their password attributes to the new password. Then it finds every `connection/param` element within each `authorize` element that has a `name="password"` attribute, and changes the text value of those too

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Twig;

use constant XML_FILE     => 'user-mapping.xml';
use constant NEW_PASSWORD => 'abc123';
use constant USER_NAME    => 'user2';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile(XML_FILE);

for my $auth ( $twig->findnodes('/user-mapping/authorize') ) {

    next unless $auth->att('username') eq USER_NAME;

    $auth->set_att(password => NEW_PASSWORD);

    for my $pass ( $auth->findnodes('connection/param[@name="password"]') ) {

        $pass->set_text(NEW_PASSWORD);

    }    
}

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print;
```

#### output

```xml
<user-mapping>
  <authorize password="abc123" username="user2">
    <connection name="U2 - Windows 7 ">
      <protocol>rdp</protocol>
      <param name="hostname">192.168.203.2</param>
      <param name="port">21122</param>
      <param name="password">abc123</param>
      <param name="username">user</param>
    </connection>
    <connection name="U2 - Windows XP SP3 ">
      <protocol>rdp</protocol>
      <param name="hostname">192.168.203.2</param>
      <param name="port">21120</param>
      <param name="password">abc123</param>
      <param name="username">user</param>
    </connection>
  </authorize>
</user-mapping>
```

Comment: I was working on an xsh extension for my answer, but with this there's no need.

Comment: @Borodin i have tested your script but i faced this issues : 
1- it will change the password for all authorize and all machines , as i said i have around 20 user that have the same ex. so how i can select authorizes where username = user3 / user 4 etc , and change passwords only for this users and corresponding machines .
2- the output is only in the terminal window, i wanted the script to change the values inside the file, i tried this but it didn't work print 
`{$XMLpath} $twig->sprint();`
3- password location is replaced with username location
Thanks alot mate .

Comment: @Ti2: ***1>>*** I have altered my code to change the passwords only for `user2` ***2>>*** Surely you know that you can redirect the output of a command to whatever file you like? It is a bad idea to write a program that modifies source data in-place as the source will be damaged if there is a bug in the program ***3>>*** I don't know what you mean by this.     *I think I have answered your question. If you can't progress then you should open a new question.*

Comment: @Borodin This is perfect man, Thanks a lot , this is exactly what i was looking for, i will add MD5 encoding as you advised , and redirect output to new file and create check integrity functions , its only 1 XML file that has all user info.
***3>>*** i meant the location of username value and password value in <authorize node > are swapped { username 1st -> password 2nd }
after edited it becomes { password 1st -> username 2nd }
 , but i think its no problem , will see if the server will be able to read it correctly or no

Answer (score 1):

Use a real XML parser. For instance, with XMLStarlet, this would be as easy as:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//authorize/@password' -v "new-password" \
  -u '//connection/param[@name="password"]' -v "new-password"
```

Comment: Yeah, except for the attributes of the `/user-mapping/authorize` elements.

Comment: Thanks to your post, I've just discovered that *XMLStarlet* is available for Windows, although I think I'd prefer an established SAX approach.